# Making a custom stack in C#

Tags: c#

So, I am trying to make a custom stack in C#. My problem is the parameter type. I want the stack to be a stack of **any parameter type** (`CustomStack<string>`, `CustomStack<int>`, `CustomStack<double>` etc).

When i declare my CustomStack class, it needs a parameter type (for example **CustomStack<int> cs = new CustomStack<int>**)

The problem is if my custom stack has a parameter type **int**, it cannot accept **doubles, strings, chars etc.**

**This is my class:**

```
public class CustomStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> stackData;

    public CustomStack()
    {
        this.stackData = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Push(params T[] items)
    {
       ...
    }

    public void Pop()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = this.stackData.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                yield return this.stackData[j];
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

**And here is my Main method:**

```
public static void Main()
    {
        CustomStack<int> customStack = new CustomStack<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter one of the following commands:");
        Console.WriteLine("PUSH - Pushes an element/s into the stack.");
        Console.WriteLine("POP - Pops an element from the stack.");
        Console.WriteLine("END - Exit the program.");
        Console.WriteLine("PRINT - Prints the stack into the console.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (input != "END")
        {
            string[] parts = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string command = parts[0];

            try
            {
                switch (command)
                {
                    case "PUSH":

                        //here is the problem.

                        var item = parts.Skip(1).ToArray();
                        int intTemp;
                        double doubleTemp;

                        if (parts.Length == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Command PUSH requires element/s to push. Example: PUSH 3; PUSH 5 6; PUSH abc def ghi;");
                        }
                        else if (int.TryParse(item[0], out intTemp))
                        {
                            customStack.Push(parts.Skip(1).Select(int.Parse).ToArray());
                        }
                        else if(double.TryParse(item[0], out doubleTemp))
                        {
                            customStack.Push(parts.Skip(1).Select(double.Parse).ToArray());
                        }

                        break;
                    case "POP":
                        customStack.Pop();
                        break;
                    case "PRINT":
                        customStack.Print();
                        break;
                    case "END":
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Command is not recognised");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter one of the following commands:");
            Console.WriteLine("PUSH - Pushes an element into the stack.");
            Console.WriteLine("POP - Pops an element from the stack.");
            Console.WriteLine("END - Exit the program.");
            Console.WriteLine("PRINT - Prints the stack into the console.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

How do i overcome this issue and have a custom stack, that accepts **ANY** type of parameter?

Comment: Why make it generic in the first place when you want to support any type in one `CustomStack`? or use `new CustomStack<object>` the generic `T` should be used to make code type safe and not support plain object, but if you requirement is any type why make it type safe?

Comment: That's what is the type-safety offered by Generics.

Comment: you _could_ use it as `CustomStack<object>`, but this all smells like a design flaw. The nice thing about c# is its type safety, which you loose this way. And your `Push` method may no longer work as expected for some kinds of arguments.

Comment: If you want your stack to be able to hold any kind of object, then you'd need a `CustomStack<object>`. Whether or not it's a good idea to do that is an entirely separate question.

Comment: You can always use `object` as the generic type, but doing so you lose all type checking by the compiler. In this particular case, both `int` and `double` are used, so you can cast all as double instead without losing int capabilities.

Comment: So you want `class CustomStack : IEnumerable<object>`?

Comment: Why you need a `CustomStack<object>`? Just declare it where you know what type it will be. Put it in a generic class that has this stack and your logic but that does not rely on the underlying type. Your issue seems to be that you want to put everything into your `Main` method.

Comment: Out of curiosity why don't you use stack as your base class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-5.0 - all the public method are declared virtual so you can override them and do your magic eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/7INS6V

Comment: @RandRandom because i just want to have my custom stack without base class, just for exercise.

Comment: When i change the class to CustomStack<object>, it literally stores any typo of variable. For example, when i print the stack, i get System.Int32, Systm.Double etc. I want it to store 1 type of variable, not variables themselves.

Comment: Why the outer loop in `GetEnumerator()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to instantiate your CustomStack object without defining the generic type but want the type to decide which generic type to use once you push an item into it.

This would mean the CustomStack does not *know* which generic type it should hold until an item is pushed. This, however, means that the generic type can not be resolved during compile time, which is a problem.

If you just want multiple CustomStack objects which hold different types then create one for each type:

```cs
var intStack = new CustomStack<int>();
var doubleStack = new CustomStack<double>();
var stringStack = new CustomStack<string>();
```

If you really want to resolve the valid type at runtime you will have to store the `Type` of the first object that is pushed by calling `object.GetType();` and test all future objects if they are of the same type. That way you wouldn't be able to use generics and would have to use the `object` type to store your items.

If you just want to store `double` and `int` types then you *could* create a CustomStack object of type `CustomStack<double>` as the double datatype is able to hold integer values. Be careful though because this can cause rounding errors when comparing your stored items with normal integers.

Answer (score 1):

The generic typing is intended to help you to create type independence at build time.

It is not intended to create type independence at run-time.

A way to overcome this, is to use `object`, as `T`, but you'll soon discover you can also omit the generic typing in that case.

There are some ways to deal with this though; some examples:

- you can create an interface to identify the allowed types
- do not combine the various types
- create "PUSH" overloads for the accepted types

Comment: Okay, i may have misled you. I want to create a custom stack, that accept ANY, not EVERY type parameter.

For example:

If i push strings to it, i want it to be a Stack<string>, if i push integers, i want it to be a Stack<int> etc.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with this than? `The problem is if my custom stack has a parameter type int, it cannot accept doubles, strings, chars etc.` --- if it is `int`, it is `int`, if you want `int` and `string`, you'll need a more flexible solution. Assuming you just want one stack, you'll need to accept more types.